# Fetch text of clicked item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I right click on a text, it pops up a menu, menu has option `Get text`, `Get id`. I want to get the text, id, link value of the selected link.

Below is my code:

```js
// when we're about to show the context menu, show our own instead
$(document).on("contextmenu", function(event) {
  // Avoid the real one if this is the link
  if ($(event.target).hasClass("sim-row-edit")) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Show contextmenu
    $(".custom-menu").show(100).
    css({
      top: event.pageY + "px",
      left: event.pageX + "px"
    });
  }
});

// hide our context menu when the document is clicked
$(document).on("mouseup", function() {
  $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
});

$(".custom-menu li").click(function() {
  alert("hii");
  // This is the triggered action name
  switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {
    // A case for each action. Should personalize to your actions
    case "first":
      console.log(this);
      break;
    case "second":
      console.log("second");
      break;
    case "third":
      console.log("third");
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
.custom-menu {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
}

.custom-menu li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.custom-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #4679BD;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="sim-row-edit" id="sim-id" data-type="link">Portfolio</a>
<ul class='custom-menu'>
  <li data-action="first">Get text,id,url of selected</li>
  <li data-action="second">Second thing</li>
  <li data-action="third">Third thing</li>
</ul>
```

When you click on `Get text,id,url of selected', I need to console log the text, href value and id of it.

Comment: Feedback: (1) quote blocks are just for quotes, and are not to be used as a general highlighter; (2) please take care to observe the rules of case here, especially using a capital "I" to refer to yourself; (3) stick to technical writing and avoid a pleading tone, especially "please guide me", "please help me", etc. Readers know you need help, and would prefer not to see begging messages.

Comment: (4) when your posts are edited, please _read_ those edits and make a note of them. Experienced editors have a great deal of knowledge about how posts are best formatted here, and it is good to learn from their edits where possible. (5) three questions in three hours is possibly a sign that you need to slow down and do more research. We're very keen here to help Stack Overflow users help themselves, and become more technically self-sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Change your selectors a bit, like so:

```js
// when we're about to show the context menu, show our own instead
$(document).on("contextmenu", function(event) {
  // Avoid the real one if this is the link
  if ($(event.target).hasClass("sim-row-edit")) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Show contextmenu
    $(".custom-menu").show(100).
    css({
      top: event.pageY + "px",
      left: event.pageX + "px"
    });
  }
});

// hide our context menu when the document is clicked
$(document).on("mouseup", function() {
  $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
});

$(".custom-menu li").click(function() {
  alert("hii");
  // This is the triggered action name
  switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {
    // A case for each action. Should personalize to your actions
    case "first":
      console.log($(this).parent().parent().children('a').text());
      console.log($(this).parent().parent().children('a').attr('id'));
      console.log($(this).parent().parent().children('a').attr('href'));
      break;
    case "second":
      console.log("second");
      break;
    case "third":
      console.log("third");
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
.custom-menu {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
}

.custom-menu li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.custom-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #4679BD;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="sim-row-edit" id="sim-id" data-type="link">Portfolio</a>
<ul class='custom-menu'>
  <li data-action="first">Get text,id,url of selected</li>
  <li data-action="second">Second thing</li>
  <li data-action="third">Third thing</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: actually i tried same, this shows the menu text clicked, which  is `Get text,id,url of selected` , where as i want `Portfolio` as i have right clicked on it

Answer (score 0):

change your switch case like below

```
 $(".custom-menu li").click(function(this) {
  alert("hii");
  // This is the triggered action name
  debugger;
  switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {
    // A case for each action. Should personalize to your actions

    case "first":
      console.log(this.innerHTML);
      break;
    case "second":
      console.log(this.innerHTML);
      break;
    case "third":
      console.log(this.innerHTML);
      break;
  }
});
```

[check the working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-7rhgtw)